# Intellisense not working in python 3.11.4

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, jupyter-notebook, intellisense

I recently installed python and jupyter notebook in my system after a format. However, after fresh installation, I am not able to activate "hinterland" extension for providing intellisense feature in jupyter notebook. I have activated nbextensions, but to no use. My python version is **3.11.4** and the version of the notebook server is: **6.5.4.** are there any workarounds to get intellisence feature in jupyter or in any way I can fix this issue? please help. Thanks!

tried changing settings in nbextensions, probably installed "hinterland" in virtual enviornment. also disable and enabled the extensions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Intellisense is not working in python 3.11.4. aar ki details chai..?